# 500 Internal Server Error when adding module

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Im have a opencart 2.3 installed with a custom theme along with a custom module that shows a product slider. The problem is that i setuped the site on my localhost and everything seem to be working perfect.

But when i uploaded it to my VPS the home page gives an internal server error when i add the module the to the home page. When i remove it, the page loads fine. This happens only on my VPS. When i uploaded it to a differnt host and my localhost everything works fine.

The main problem is that i cannot find the actual error which is causing the problem because the apache error logs doesnt log any php related errors.

so far,

- i removed the htaccess
- enable error reporting through htaccess
- removed extra php.ini file which might be conflicting
- added the error reporting code on the index.php file
- checked the opencart error logs

none of these seem to work. It shows the internal server error instead of the actual error. For almost 2 weeks i have been struggling and tried almost all the methods in SO but none seems to be working in my case

Can someone let me know how can i get it show the actual error or log it instead of the internal server error?

Comment: If you can access error log on your server, ask your server provider regarding error log, which should be on your server. Seems some module or even the theme can cause this problem. 
Or you can try step by step disabling and removing files of all third party modules and themes.

Comment: @K.B. I have full access to the server.. When i check the error logs there is nothing related to the php errors.. When i disable the module it works on the vps. But the exact same copy of the website on my local host works fine with those modules enabled.. also when i upload it to a different host it works.. I dont get the internal server error. So i assume there is nothing wrong with the module.

Comment: have you checked your server php version?

Comment: @K.B. yep.. Its PHP 7.. The exact same version as in the shared hosting

Comment: have you tried inspect it with browser console? click  F12 (on most browsers) to open it.

Comment: Agree with @K.B. looking at the network traffic may give a little more info

Comment: how is it possible that apache is not logging a 500 error?  that's a new one on me.  applications generally can't log 500 errors because php has crashed at the server level.  this question is unanswerable until you can get error reporting working on your server.